# Why is this index status red: opendistro-ism-config

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't think I have ever even touched this index, but it is making my entire cluster have a status of red. Don't know what it is or how to fix it, tried adding another node but didn't work.
In the index management view I can see that it is the only index which is red. The problem index is `opendistro-ism-config`. I tried changing the number of replicas for the index, adding a node, etc, didn't help.

**Edit**

As asked by @Val I have added the following query. My index stays in a red status, which spam alarms me on AWS where I've deployed my cluster. I have allot of indices so I removed them from the output in `shard_sizes` , and just left he one in question. I've got `4 x t2.small` 35 GiB SSDs, plenty of spare space in the cluster. This isn't my prod cluster so it's not too bad, but is very annoying.

```
https://{{ES_DOMAIN}}/_cluster/allocation/explain?include_disk_info&include_yes_decisions
```

```
{
    "index": ".opendistro-ism-config",
    "shard": 1,
    "primary": true,
    "current_state": "unassigned",
    "unassigned_info": {
        "reason": "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
        "at": "2020-08-01T09:18:40.288Z",
        "failed_allocation_attempts": 5,
        "details": "failed shard on node [ex3PL3THRHmAxkvMjOwrQQ]: failed to create shard, failure IOException[failed to obtain in-memory shard lock]; nested: ShardLockObtainFailedException[[.opendistro-ism-config][1]: obtaining shard lock timed out after 5000ms, previous lock details: [shard creation] trying to lock for [shard creation]]; ",
        "last_allocation_status": "no_valid_shard_copy"
    },
    "cluster_info": {
        "nodes": {
            "KnCBTiL1TZCGz1DNYfm9_A": {
                "node_name": "ef9116cc46563e2c73d12eb7a8887f4c",
                "least_available": {
                    "total_bytes": 36722737152,
                    "used_bytes": 2143232000,
                    "free_bytes": 34579505152,
                    "free_disk_percent": 94.2,
                    "used_disk_percent": 5.8
                },
                "most_available": {
                    "total_bytes": 36722737152,
                    "used_bytes": 2143232000,
                    "free_bytes": 34579505152,
                    "free_disk_percent": 94.2,
                    "used_disk_percent": 5.8
                }
            },
            "90rKZw_SSOSlOGWv_WyQQQ": {
                "node_name": "45cfd2c275112972c5e68e7e00295d45",
                "least_available": {
                    "total_bytes": 36722737152,
                    "used_bytes": 2144980992,
                    "free_bytes": 34577756160,
                    "free_disk_percent": 94.2,
                    "used_disk_percent": 5.8
                },
                "most_available": {
                    "total_bytes": 36722737152,
                    "used_bytes": 2144980992,
                    "free_bytes": 34577756160,
                    "free_disk_percent": 94.2,
                    "used_disk_percent": 5.8
                }
            },
            "2F_QTYueTs69Q7KhCped9w": {
                "node_name": "a8314d5f13c0043f8454997d973e8c03",
                "least_available": {
                    "total_bytes": 36722737152,
                    "used_bytes": 1957380096,
                    "free_bytes": 34765357056,
                    "free_disk_percent": 94.7,
                    "used_disk_percent": 5.3
                },
                "most_available": {
                    "total_bytes": 36722737152,
                    "used_bytes": 1957380096,
                    "free_bytes": 34765357056,
                    "free_disk_percent": 94.7,
                    "used_disk_percent": 5.3
                }
            },
            "8-oMtA69QvO3bKTAAUPeBw": {
                "node_name": "9c042bb3814270c16b4fba03ff85208d",
                "least_available": {
                    "total_bytes": 36722737152,
                    "used_bytes": 2140692480,
                    "free_bytes": 34582044672,
                    "free_disk_percent": 94.2,
                    "used_disk_percent": 5.8
                },
                "most_available": {
                    "total_bytes": 36722737152,
                    "used_bytes": 2140692480,
                    "free_bytes": 34582044672,
                    "free_disk_percent": 94.2,
                    "used_disk_percent": 5.8
                }
            }
        },
        "shard_sizes": {
            "[.opendistro-ism-config][2][r]_bytes": 56497,
            "[.opendistro-ism-config][0][p]_bytes": 53651,
            "[.opendistro-ism-config][0][r]_bytes": 53651,
            "[.opendistro-ism-config][4][p]_bytes": 33157,
            "[.opendistro-ism-config][2][p]_bytes": 56497
            }
        },
        "can_allocate": "no_valid_shard_copy",
        "allocate_explanation": "cannot allocate because a previous copy of the primary shard existed but can no longer be found on the nodes in the cluster",
        "node_allocation_decisions": [
            {
                "node_id": "2F_QTYueTs69Q7KhCped9w",
                "node_name": "a8314d5f13c0043f8454997d973e8c03",
                "node_decision": "no",
                "store": {
                    "found": false
                }
            },
            {
                "node_id": "8-oMtA69QvO3bKTAAUPeBw",
                "node_name": "9c042bb3814270c16b4fba03ff85208d",
                "node_decision": "no",
                "store": {
                    "found": false
                }
            },
            {
                "node_id": "90rKZw_SSOSlOGWv_WyQQQ",
                "node_name": "45cfd2c275112972c5e68e7e00295d45",
                "node_decision": "no",
                "store": {
                    "found": false
                }
            },
            {
                "node_id": "KnCBTiL1TZCGz1DNYfm9_A",
                "node_name": "ef9116cc46563e2c73d12eb7a8887f4c",
                "node_decision": "no",
                "store": {
                    "found": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you run this and update your question with the result you get? `GET _cluster/allocation/explain?include_disk_info&include_yes_decisions`

Comment: @Val I have added the query like you asked, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***A workaround to make your cluster working again is manually rerouting
> the shard.***

**Problem reason** : It mostly happens if there was a primary with no replicas allocated to the node when it got disconnected from the master. So, When rejoining the cluster, the locally allocated shard copy on the node isn't able to free previously used resources in the time where the master had already made 5 attempts to unsuccessfully allocate the shard to the node again.

After 5 unsuccessful allocation attempts, the master gives up and needs manual triggering to give it another allocation.

**Solution** : Run below command to resolve the same :

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed
```

Comment: Seems this is not allowed for an AWS cluster.

Answer (score 1):

RED cluster status means one or more primary index is missing and it might not be having any replica to that primary shard or es is not able to promote replica to primary shard.

Please follow [official ES blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/red-elasticsearch-cluster-panic-no-longer) to troubleshoot the issue.

Adding another node wouldn't help, if you don't have the replica shard also missing for lost primary shard.